# Flutter get Mac Address from iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, wifi, mac-address

i have tried to get the mac address from device, on Android i don't have any problems, but on iOS the device give me iOS version instead of MAC Address.

I use this:

```
import 'package:macadress_gen/macadress_gen.dart';

MacadressGen macadressGen = MacadressGen();
await macadressGen.getMac();
```

i have tried variously package but the resault it is the same

On my phisical iPhone i have disabled private address from WiFi settings

Comment: Apple does not allow apps to obtain the device MAC address for privacy reasons.

Comment: but you can disable the private connection from the wifi settings

Comment: An app being able to read the MAC address is completely different.  Unrelated apps from different developers could get the same identifier (the MAC) and use this to track a user's activity across those unrelated apps.  Further, the user can't reset this identifier, even by erasing the device.  This is why Apple blocked access to the MAC address many years ago.  Apps can make use of `identifierForVendor` which is a unique identifier for that developer on a particular device or the advertising identifier (which the user can block through ATT and reset whenever they want)

Answer (score 0):

Try this mac_address package which should surely work [this is the package link](https://pub.dev/packages/mac_address/install)

Here is the example how to excute it :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mac_address/mac_address.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
 }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
   String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

 @override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initPlatformState();
}

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async 
method.
   Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
   String platformVersion;
   // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
  try {
     platformVersion = await GetMac.macAddress;
   } on PlatformException {
    platformVersion = 'Failed to get Device MAC Address.';
   }

   // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous 
platform
  // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than 
calling
  // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
   if (!mounted) return;

   setState(() {
     _platformVersion = platformVersion;
   });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('MAC Address : $_platformVersion\n'),
    ),
  ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this package, but i have the same result